# C - matrix from file

Tags: c

I know that was a lot of questions and answers about "loading matrix from file in C". But I have one problem and question.

My piece of code looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; fgets(buffer_char, 256, file); i++) {
    tmp_char = strtok(buffer_char, " \t");

    for(int j=0; tmp_char != NULL; j++) {
        printf("%s ", tmp_char);
        strtod(tmp_char, array[i][j]);
        tmp_char = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }
}
```

I have input file with matrix like:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
5 6 7
```

I'm trying to load it into array, but I have to check if input values are correct. And my question is, How I can do it better? Which solution will be more correct?

@edit:

I modified code to this:

```
for(int i=0; fgets(buffer_char, 256, file); i++) {
    array[i][0] = strtod(buffer_char, &tmp_char);
    for(int j=1; tmp_char == NULL; j++) {
        array[i][j] = strtod(tmp_char, &tmp_char);
    }
}
```

And it works, How I want, but only for first elements of new line. I know, the problem is with "array[i][j] = strtod(tmp_char, &tmp_char);", but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: That call to [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) doesn't look correct. It *returns* the converted value.

Comment: use `fscanf` instead `fgets` for validating input

Comment: That is a creative but not idiomatic way to write those loops. `i` and `j` would be better limited to the array available.

Comment: Lake of info in your code, how do you know the size of the matrix? You need to alloc the array first, so you need to read the first char and alloc the matrix and loop on this value

Comment: @EliadCohen: first line of input.txt means size of matrix.

Comment: So why does the code not read and use that information?

Comment: The `i` and `j`  should not be grater than the first char, "the size"

Comment: The problem is a simple case of using `scanf` rightly. Making mountain out of molehill, given the example input.

Comment: Never mind the edit, you still don't show how the array is defined. The sample input shows integers, so why are you using `strtod`? Unclear what you are asking. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: Look what i have wrote, use atoi, this is better then strtod (i think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `fscanf` for validating and storing your input into an array.

Code:

```
  if((check=fscanf(fp,"%d",&n))==1)
  {

    int Arr[n][n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         fscanf(fp,"%d",&Arr[i][j]);
         printf("%d ",Arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: He will never lent this way :)

Comment: Ok, but what if I give the size 3, and I type 4 elements in a row?

Comment: I think you should use `fgets` after the second `for` to read all the line. remove the second `fscanf` and it should work

Comment: if size is `n` it will take _n x n_ elements, no matters you type 4 or 5 element in a row.

Comment: if your file contain more than `n` elements in a row then that's the different thing, you can use `fgets` for taking input from second line,and then copy only first 3 elements from `n` lines

Comment: @krpra this is not true, because in the second `scanf` you read num by num without consider the new line.

Comment: @EliadCohen yeah that's what the code is doing, what's your point, clear that.

Comment: @krpra that is what i'm saying , this code is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157244/discussion-between-krpra-and-eliad-cohen).